Cookie and subdomain
Say website A makes request to website B.
If B sets cookies for A, then every subsequent A-to-B request has that cookie header. I got this. But what about subdomain?

Does sub.A-to-B request share that cookie?
Does A-to-sub.B request share that cookie?

I read many MDN pages and several anắners about my above questions, but can't understand the terminology.

When A makes request to B and B set cookies, does that means the cookie is sent to A (in the response) or sent to B (in the subsequent request)?
What does for means? The cookies in the example is considered for A or B?

Thanks!

Websites don't make requests to each other, so your question is confusing.  When a client makes a request to a site, it CAN request that the client sets a cookie.  Clients send any cookies they have for a domain in every subsequent HTTP request, in the HTTP header.  It is up to the client to both set/save and send cookies to the server.

This question is similar to: Share cookies between subdomain and domain. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
